# ValueAnimator doesn't trigger properties methods

Tags: android

I had been debugged the following code for whole day, and have no idea why it doesn't work as expected.

```
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.PropertyValuesHolder;
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator;

private void animateThumbCoorToMatchCurrentIndixes() {
    float newThumbLeftCoor = this.indexToCoor(this.thumbLeftIndex);
    float newThumbRightCoor = this.indexToCoor(this.thumbRightIndex);

    PropertyValuesHolder thumbLeftPropertyValuesHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("thumbLeftCoor", this.thumbLeftCoor, newThumbLeftCoor);
    PropertyValuesHolder thumbRightPropertyValuesHolder = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("thumbRightCoor", this.thumbRightCoor, newThumbRightCoor);

    Log.i("CHEOK", "Animate " + this.thumbLeftCoor + " -> " + newThumbLeftCoor);
    Log.i("CHEOK", "Animate " + this.thumbRightCoor + " -> " + newThumbRightCoor);

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this, thumbLeftPropertyValuesHolder, thumbRightPropertyValuesHolder);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime));
    valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(0);
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    Log.i("CHEOK", "Animation duration = " + valueAnimator.getDuration());

    valueAnimator.start();
}

// Do not remove this code. It is used for reflection call for animation.
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void setThumbLeftCoor(float thumbLeftCoor) {
    this.thumbLeftCoor = thumbLeftCoor;
    Log.i("CHEOK", "SET thumbLeftCoor " + thumbLeftCoor);
    this.postInvalidate();
}

// Do not remove this code. It is used for reflection call for animation.
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void setThumbRightCoor(float thumbRightCoor) {
    this.thumbRightCoor = thumbRightCoor;
    Log.i("CHEOK", "SET thumbRightCoor " + thumbRightCoor);
    this.postInvalidate();
}
```

My console log is as follow :

```
Animate 636.0985 -> 0.0
Animate 679.27057 -> 578.0
Animation duration = 200
```

**However, methods `setThumbLeftCoor` and `setThumbRightCoor` never get triggered.**

Anyone have idea why it happens so?

Comment: Why do you use `ValueAnimator`? Try to use `ObjectAnimator` instead.

Comment: `ObjectAnimator` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the while, by having `setThumbLeftCoor` and `setThumbRightCoor` as **private** method work for my case.

Just that recently, a child class is being derived from the above class.

To make the above code work as it is, changing `setThumbLeftCoor` and `setThumbRightCoor` to **public** method is required. (Even **protected** won't work)

My guess is, this is due to limitation of "reflection"